# LDAP (with ppolicy) errors on changing other user's password

Tags: ldap, openldap

I've set up an LDAP server with the ppolicy overlay, but now am having trouble resetting user's password in some cases: if the user has a failed login, then the pwdFailureTime attribute exists and ldapmodify fails complaining that it doesn't.

If my most recent log-in attempt was successful, then I can bind as cn=admin and run the ldif file:

```
dn: uid=anton,ou=accounts,dc=[redacted],dc=ca
changetype: modify
replace: userPassword
userPassword: foobar
-
replace: pwdReset
pwdReset: TRUE
```

which succeeds.  However, if the last log-in attempt was with a wrong password, ppolicy adds a pwdFailureTime attribute to the account, and then trying to run the ldif file above results in:

```
$ ldapmodify -x -D "cn=admin,dc=[redacted],dc=ca" -W -H ldap:// -f pwreset.ldif
Enter LDAP Password: 
modifying entry "uid=anton,ou=accounts,dc=[redacted],dc=ca"
ldap_modify: No such attribute (16)
    additional info: modify/delete: pwdFailureTime: no such attribute
```

If I try deleting the pwdFailureTime attribute before resetting the password, then I get:

```
ldap_modify: Constraint violation (19)
    additional info: pwdFailureTime: no user modification allowed
```

In real life, if a user's forgotten their password and needs it reset, they will generally have tried to recall the password several times, so will have the pwdFailureTime attribute set.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As for the [IETF draft](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-behera-ldap-password-policy-10.html) states :

> 8.2.7. Policy State Updates
>
> If the steps have completed without causing an error condition, the
>   server performs the following steps in order to update the necessary
>   password policy state attributes:
>
> If the value of either pwdMaxAge or pwdMinAge is non-zero, the server
>   updates the pwdChangedTime attribute on the entry to the current time.
>
> If the value of pwdInHistory is non-zero, the server adds the previous
>   password (if one existed) to the pwdHistory attribute. If the number
>   of attributes held in the pwdHistory attribute exceeds the value of
>   pwdInHistory, the server removes the oldest excess passwords.
>
> If the value the pwdMustChange is TRUE and the modification is
>   performed by a password administrator, then the pwdReset attribute is
>   set to TRUE. Otherwise, the pwdReset is removed from the user's entry
>   if it exists.
>
> The pwdFailureTime and pwdGraceUseTime attributes is removed from the
>   user's entry if they exist.

If I'm not mistaken, LDIF is atomic operations, so when the `userPassword` is modified, it chains to removing the `pwdFailureTime` attribute, hence why when the modification of `pwdReset` which seems to trigger also the removing of `pwdFailureTime` fails.

Why do you need to set the `pwdReset` to `TRUE` ? You already reset it. If it is to ensure that the user must "reset" himself the password at the first connection :

may be try instead to modify the `pwsMustChange` attribute to `TRUE`, which should set the `pwdReset` attribute to `TRUE`(according to the IETF on which is based the OpenLDAP ppolicy)

or may be just switch the two modifications on the LDIF could do the trick.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get back to this until now.  I've left pwdMustChange as FALSE, because mostly my users will be interacting through a web page, which I've put together using PHP, which only has an ldap_modify, which someone with pwdReset=TRUE wouldn't have permission to use...  Removing the lines resetting pwdReset doesn't change the error, and I get the same error using phpLdapAdmin, or using ldappasswd at the command line.

Comment: Ah, however, if I switch the two modifications in the LDIF, then it appears to work.  I did hit some other issues, which all seem to centre around the problem that if any policies in ppolicy are triggered, these create internal attributes, and then password changes fail because those attributes don't exist (but only where they actually do).  So I guess the workaround for now is to basically not use any of the policies.